Updating multiple managed metadata columns in a single update
We're working on a job to sync some data to SharePoint 2019 using CSOM.
        private static void SetLookupsItemValue(ClientContext context, List list, IEnumerable<Column> lookupColumns, Dictionary<string, object> sysItem, ListItem spItem)
    {
        foreach (Column column in lookupColumns)
        {
            if (column.SpType == "TermStore" && (!sysItem[column.sysName].Equals(DBNull.Value)))
            {
                Field field = GetField(context, list, column.SpName);
                TaxonomyField txField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);

                string label = sysItem[column.sysName].ToString();

                if (label.Contains("&"))
                {
                    label = label.Replace("&", "\uFF06");
                }

                if (column.SpName == "Buy_List" && label.Contains(";"))
                {
                    TaxonomyFieldValueCollection newTerm = GetTaxonomyFieldCollectionValueForFieldLabel(context, field, column, label);
                    txField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(spItem, newTerm);
                }

                else
                {
                    TaxonomyFieldValue newTerm = GetTaxonomyFieldValueForFieldLabel(context, field, column, label);
                    txField.SetFieldValueByValue(spItem, newTerm);
                }
            }
            else if (column.SpType == "User" && !(sysItem[column.sysName].Equals(DBNull.Value)))
            {
                FieldUserValue userValue = GetUserFieldValueForDisplayName(context, sysItem[column.sysName].ToString());
                spItem[column.SpName] = userValue;
            }
        }
        spItem.Update();
        context.ExecuteQuery();
    }

This code identifies the correct term to be used for each column and updates the context. It executes all updates together at the end. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to update the values of the managed metadata columns, we're seeing nothing come through.
    private static void SetLookupsItemValue(ClientContext context, List list, IEnumerable<Column> lookupColumns, Dictionary<string, object> sysItem, ListItem spItem)
    {
        foreach (Column column in lookupColumns)
        {
            if (column.SpType == "TermStore" && (!sysItem[column.sysName].Equals(DBNull.Value)))
            {
                Field field = GetField(context, list, column.SpName);
                TaxonomyField txField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);

                string label = sysItem[column.sysName].ToString();

                if (label.Contains("&"))
                {
                    label = label.Replace("&", "\uFF06");
                }

                if (column.SpName == "Buy_List" && label.Contains(";"))
                {
                    TaxonomyFieldValueCollection newTerm = GetTaxonomyFieldCollectionValueForFieldLabel(context, field, column, label);
                    txField.SetFieldValueByValueCollection(spItem, newTerm);
                }

                else
                {
                    TaxonomyFieldValue newTerm = GetTaxonomyFieldValueForFieldLabel(context, field, column, label);
                    txField.SetFieldValueByValue(spItem, newTerm);
                }
            }
            else if (column.SpType == "User" && !(sysItem[column.sysName].Equals(DBNull.Value)))
            {
                FieldUserValue userValue = GetUserFieldValueForDisplayName(context, sysItem[column.sysName].ToString());
                spItem[column.SpName] = userValue;
            }
            spItem.Update();
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }

This code (note the Update and Execute now inside the loop) sends through the correct changes but as individual updates per column, not as one change. This means our list versioning is being polluted by up to 20 updates per update.
How can we get multiple Managed Metadata columns to update in one list item version?

As an additional note - we've also tried the spItem.Update() inside the loop and the context.ExecuteQuery() outside the loop with no updates going through.
